# A Way for Presenting Useful Links in the Website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in my senior project which is a web-based system and I want to dedicate one page of the website for some useful links that are related to my website. I tried to present them in such an innovative way like showing a brief description (in a balloon or a new line or anything) about the link when the mouse comes over it.

I heard there are some JQuery templates for that. I tried to search about them but I did not get anything.

So could you please help me in this issue?
Please provide me with any guide that is helpful to do this issue.
Also, please provide me with your suggestions for presenting the useful links in somehow a nice way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is a tooltip. I like the tooltip component from [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) quite a lot, and the documentation is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like Simpletip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/, or it's successor qTip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/ (hat tip @Edmund Y).

If you look at this Xmarks page, it pretty much lists all of the most popular JQuery tooltip plugins: http://www.xmarks.com/topic/jquery_tooltip, sorted by the number of people that have bookmarked them!

Comment: according to the site for simpletip, qTip replaces simpletip and qTip2 replaces qTip http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download

Comment: @Edmund - Indeed you're right! Ironically Simpletip appeared higher in my search results! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use JQuery!

What you want can be achieved using only CSS.

Utilizing the :hover selector, its possible to display a box over your link when you move your mouse over it.

[Here's a good link to get started.](http://psacake.com/web/jl.asp)